# ExtJS 6-- Add textfield control into dynamic grid column header

Tags: extjs, header, grid, components

I am trying to add a textfield (or combobox) into the column header of dynamic grid.

There are suggestions for using "items" property to resolve this problem like in example below (line 81 in live [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30h9) ):

```js
   ...
        text: 'Email',
        flex: 1,
        menuDisabled: true,
        sortable: false,
        dataIndex: 'email',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            labelWidth: 40,
            flex: 1,
            fieldLabel: 'Email'
        }]
   ...
```

And it basically works but, there are several issues with layout which I cannot resolve myself:

1. textfield control appears under the column title (expect horizontal items alignment);
2. height of column header is to big (must be normal);

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht97Q.png) what I want to get.

Also, there is a live [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30h9) in the fiddle with mentioned issues.

Are there any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were just about there, here are the code changes I made.

```
function getColumnConfigs() {
return [{
    text: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    flex: 1
}, {
    text: '',
    flex: 1,
    menuDisabled: true,
    sortable: false,
    dataIndex: 'email',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        store: ages,
        valueField: 'age',
        displayField: 'age',
        labelWidth: 40,
        padding: '0 0 0 10',
        flex: 1,
        fieldLabel: 'Age'
    }]
}]
```

The code removes your text attribute so it doesn't show the column header. Padding was added to the combobox to move the label right. I added the combobox rather than a textfield.

And a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30hn).

Comment: Thank you for response! It looks almost what I am looking for, but there is one important issue. Empty column header placeholder (`text: ''`) still present and becomes visible on mouse over. Is it possible completely remove it ( or hide ) from column header?

Comment: That is the mouse over event on the the column header. So I'm not aware of a way or why you would be concerned with this action. Personally I would want them to be able to sort on age. Maybe via a custom override it might be accomplished.

Comment: Partial header highlighting looks at least strange. Therefore, it would be better to hide it at all. I have overridden a `hoverCls: ''` property under `dataIndex: 'email'` to disable mouse over effect. Thanks!